# NullPointerException when cancel progressDialog to go back another activity

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

Anyone know what is going on at here? Is there any way to allow user to cancel the progressDialog and go back to Activity A without having any crash ?

**Steps to reproduce this crash :**

In an **activity A** and I start a new intent **Activity B** tabhost that load "class1.java" (Webview with progressDialog) before the progressDialog load finish , i quicky hit the back button to go back to **Activity A** and i got a crash

**The apps won't crash if :**

- I wait till the webview load finish and go back to Activity A
- I cancel the progressDialog and stay on the webview till the page load finish and go back to Activity A

**Line 51 :** progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);

**Logcat :** http://pastebin.com/uBw4xcaY

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.domain.package.ui.class1$class1_$1.onProgressChanged(class1.java:51)
at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:358)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's my code :

```
[...]

public class class1 extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_stack);

}

public static class class1_ extends Fragment {

    /** The Fragment's UI **/
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.class_, container, false);

        WebView engine = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.web_engine);

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.show();

        engine.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

                progressDialog.setProgress(0);
                getActivity().setProgress(progress * 1000);

                progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);

                if (progress == 100 && progressDialog.isShowing())
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

            engine.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            engine.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
            engine.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
            engine.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");


        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "Hello this is a toast",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return v;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: **Line 51 :** progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);
**Logcat :** http://pastebin.com/uBw4xcaY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your `onChanged()` method like this:

```
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
  if( progressDialog.isShowing() ) {
    progressDialog.setProgress(0);
    getActivity().setProgress(progress * 1000);

    progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);

    if ( progress == 100 )
      progressDialog.dismiss();
  }
}
```

And then add this to the fragments `onPause()` method:

```
if( progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing() )
  dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: Thanks problem solved ; what will happen if I don't include that code you given into onPause() ?

Comment: Maybe it's not needed - but you might end up leaking the dialog (that will show up in your logcat) on orientation change or when you hit the back button.

Answer (score 3):

When you cancel `Dialog` and go back, the `Dialog` is set to `null` but your `WebChromeClient` callback is still loading and when progress is changed, progress is set on `Dialog`, but the `Dialog` is `null` so cause `NullPointerException`. Modify your `setWebChromeClient()` as.

```
engine.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
      public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            if(progressDialog != null)
                progressDialog.setProgress(0);
                getActivity().setProgress(progress * 1000);
                progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(progress);
                if (progress == 100 && progressDialog.isShowing())
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
      }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you help and explanation , too bad stackoverflow don't allow to choose 2 answer ; anyway I will include your name in my app credit list if you want :)